# Inline style to subclass JavaFX

Tags: java, css, javafx

I´d like to apply this style programatically:

```
.rating:disabled > .container:disabled .button:disabled{
    -fx-pref-height:15;
    -fx-background-size: cover;
    -fx-padding: 0; 
}
```

I have tried this, but doesnt work:

```
    ratingHeigth.bind(mainBorderPane.prefHeightProperty().divide(0.0355));
    vipRating.styleProperty().bind(Bindings.concat(".rating:disabled > .container:disabled .button:disabled{ -fx-pref-height: ", ratingHeigth.asString(), ";}"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is undocumented behavior, as far as I am aware (so you might not want to rely on it), but you can create a "looked-up-size" in a similar manner to a "looked-up color" (which is documented).

In your external CSS stylesheet, do

```css
.rating {
    disabled-button-size: 15 ;
}

.rating:disabled > .container:disabled .button:disabled{
    -fx-pref-height: disabled-button-size ;
    -fx-background-size: cover;
    -fx-padding: 0; 
}
```

Then in Java do

```
vipRating.styleProperty().bind(ratingHeight.asString("disabled-button-size: %f ;"));
```

Your code doesn't work, because inline styles simply apply the actual style specified by the string to the node on which you call `setStyle(...)`: an inline style does not include selectors.

The idea in the solution above is to define a "looked-up size" (sort of a CSS variable) in the CSS file that defines the height you want. Then use `setStyle` to change the value of that "looked-up size". This value is inherited by child nodes, so it's enough to set it using `setStyle` on a the container with the `rating` CSS class.

Here's a (simpler) SSCCE. Move the slider and the button will change size:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.binding.IntegerBinding;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextFormatter;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class LookedUpSizeTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button button = new Button("Test");
        StackPane stack = new StackPane(button);
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(stack);

        Slider sizeSlider = new Slider(30, 350, 40);

        stack.styleProperty().bind(sizeSlider.valueProperty().asString("button-size: %f ;"));

        root.setBottom(sizeSlider);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("style.css");

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

style.css:

```css
.root {
    button-size: 20 ;
}
.button {
    -fx-pref-height: button-size ;
}
```

Comment: Thank you my friend, I am days looking for it.

Comment: @James_D, seems that this trick dont work for `-fx-font-size`, I am trying to bind the `.table-column .label {
    -fx-font-size: label-size;
}` but isnt working. Any new trick?

Comment: Just discover that for `-fx-font-size`, you can apply direct to node and will work for the selectors.